# How to use arrays with Spring Data JDBC

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to use Spring Data JDBC for my PostgreSQL database. I defined the following beans

```java
@Data
class Report {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Set<Dimension> dimensions;

}

@Data
class Dimension {

    private String name;

    private Long[] filterIds;

}
```

and the corresponding DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE report (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dimension (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY ,
    report bigint,
    name text,
    filter_ids bigint[],
    FOREIGN KEY (report) REFERENCES report(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Then I tried to insert a report

```java
final Dimension dimension = new Dimension();

dimension.setName("xyz");
dimension.setFilterIds(new Long[]{ 1L, 2L, 3L });

final Report report = new Report();

report.setName("xyz");
report.setDimensions(Collections.singleton(dimension));

repository.save(report);
```

where `repository` is simply a `CrudRepository<Report, Long>`.

This gave me the following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "filter_ids" is of type bigint[] but expression is of type bigint
  Hinweis: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 116
```

Can I somehow tell Spring Data JDBC how to map the array types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the release of Spring Data JDBC 1.1.0, this became possible. See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.types):

> The properties of the following types are currently supported:
>
> - All primitive types and their boxed types (int, float, Integer, Float, and so on)
> - Enums get mapped to their name.
> - String
> - java.util.Date, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDateTime, and java.time.LocalTime
> - **Arrays and Collections of the types mentioned above can be mapped to columns of array type if your database supports that.**
> - ...

Answer (score 3):

As [*P44T* answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073356/66686) this should work from version of 1.1 of Spring Data JDBC onwards just as you used it.

**Original answer**

It is currently not possible. There are issues for this. A starting point is this one: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-259